# Could Data have floored Khan with a single punch?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data, star-trek-into-darkness

In *Star Trek Into Darkness*, Khan invites Captain Kirk to punch him. Kirk does, repeatedly, and Khan is totally unaffected.

Suppose that Data were on the scene instead of Kirk, and Khan, thinking that Data is a Frenchman, extends the same invitation. Data puts his full strength into his punch and nails Khan in the face. Does Khan go down immediately?

If this is an outlawed sort of question, then I'm sorry. But I think that an objective analysis can be given, since both Data's strength and Khan's durability can be determined to some degree.

Comment: Data's strength is highly discussed and contested. He's been shown carrying a 300lb anvil in one hand, and easily bending a bar able to withstand 40k bars (580 000 psi, or lb per inch). Using either of these figures, since Data's hand is roughly hand-sized, I'd imagine he could have punched clean through Khan's face.

Comment: Yeah, while no one could contest that Khan has super strength, that is relative to humans. Khan is still a human made out of flesh and bone. These things have set limits. Data's strength simply beyond human physical tolerances - enhanced or not.

Comment: For starters, Khan would know immediately that Data wasn't human, French or otherwise. But... yea.

Comment: This is called 'Shark vs Gorilla'

Comment: @JackBNimble - The defining feature of Shark vs Gorilla is that it transcends universes. Pitting two individuals within the **same** universe is better characterised as Shark vs Shark.

Comment: +1 for the Time's Arrow reference :)

Comment: Many of the questions on this website are opinion-based. Why aren't they also put on hold?

Answer (score 22):

I think it's reasonable to assume that Data could kill Khan with a single punch. For me, the real question is whether Data has enough strength to literally **punch through Khan's head and out the other side**. In short, I'd say that the answer is an unqualified **yes.**

- Data is known to possess physical strength far in excess of a human and the ability to move at incredible speeds. He is described in TNG : Measure of a Man as having "mega strength" and in TNG : The Naked Now we see him moving his hands so fast that they literally become a blur.
- In Star Trek : First Contact, Data punches through the wall of a coolant tank. Since this was almost certainly made of [transparent aluminium](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transparent_aluminum), I think we can call this a good analogue for an Enhanced-Human's skull.

[image]

- We see Data punch Riker in TNG : Power Play. From a seated position, he literally smacks him eight feet across the room without any apparent difficulty.

[image]

Comment: Not to mention snapping Worf's wrist with no effort in "Clues".

Comment: @omegacron - I was trying to find instances of 'explosive' punches rather than mere strength. You're not wrong though.

Comment: It was Paxan Troi that broke Worf's wrist. You don't think that Khan could knock Riker down, as Data does?

Comment: It's unclear to me how Riker got back up. A blow of that magnitude should have broken several bones in his ribcage, collapsing a lung or causing cardiac arrest.

Comment: Perhaps he was wearing a bulletproof vest.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in Descent part 1 Data tosses a Borg with one hand.

Comment: I really hope when they filmed that scene they did a take where Jonathan Frakes flew back all campy like that and Patrick Stewart nodded his head approvingly and said "acting!"

Comment: Yeah Data could pretty much, you know, run the whole show. But he was too preoccupied with being human. And Lore was programmed to be the ultimate wanker. Sung had some mad skills though. It's somehow extremely Star Trek that personality is the hardest thing to get right :)

Comment: You'd think a $45 million budget would buy a more realistic looking "deadly gas containment tube" than green acetate paper that flops around at the slightest touch.

Comment: Didn't Data also knock out a Klingon by _receiving_ a headbutt? Admittedly, the force involved is more due to the Klingon in question, but it shows an example of Data's durability (capable of surviving a fatal blow the Khan without damage).

Comment: @T-1000 yes and no - that was a different episode. Data did it in "Clues". One of the clues was that Worf's wrist had a major fracture that couldn't be accounted for. We later see that Data did it. When asked who was strong enough to break his wrist, Worf replied that maybe 3 individuals on board had that level of strength, including Data.

Comment: @Omegacron You're not remembering correctly. "Clues" is the episode in which Data repeatedly lies to the crew---I asked a question about it---in order to protect the Enterprise from the xenophobic Paxans. The Paxans have the ability to take over the bodies of humanoids, and they do so with Troi. It is Paxan Troi that breaks Worf's wrist, not Data.

Comment: You are correct, sir. I remembered the scene with Worf (A warrior does NOT complain about discomfort) and him stating that Data was one of the few who could do it, but was thinking it actually was Data who did the deed. Earlier I thought you were referring to the episode where energy beings (prisoners) possessed Troi, Data, & O'Brien.